# How to upload a large file in pieces to my server?

Tags: files, upload

How can upload a large SQL dump file it's 1GB, is there any software that uploads the file and resumes it later or just cut it into pieces and then join them back on the server ?
because ftp upload is not an option (slow connection).
and thanks

Comment: You need to give more information.  SQL yes, but what platform.  If FTP is not an option, what is? (ie. what upload mechanisms *are* available to you.)

Comment: Why's wrong with FTP over a slow connection? Any other transfer protocol is still going to be limited by the slow connection.

Answer (score 5):

You don't mention your operating systems. I'm assuming you use a flavor of Linux.

Linux systems have a CLI utility called 'split' that is expressly intended to break a file into pieces. To reassemble, you just 'cat' the files together.

Comment: the hosting company uses linux, and where can I find this utility on my server ?

Comment: Should be just 'split' - it's a "standard" piece of software. On CentOS, it's explicit location is /usr/bin/split. For usage, do "man split" to merge files, use cat. eg "cat sourcefile >> destfile"

Answer (score 3):

This is [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)'s bread and butter.

rsync's --partial argument will cause it to resume a partially transmitted file. SQL will probably compress well (if it's not already gzipped, or similar), so you may want to consider the -z option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rar file with the option -v and split it up into several files. Load them up and unpack the rar files.

In addition: If you are uploading a mysql dump. Zip it upfront, it will be way smaller than and mysql can handle zipped files.

Comment: if I use the first option how can extract them n my server that the question, I thought about that.

Comment: just unrar the first file. rest should follow.